# Black box instead of iframe youtube video

Tags: html

The code provided below is present in an html file.  When opening the file in Firefox there is a black box being shown instead of the video.  Does this mean an addon, extension, or application needs updating or a setting in Firefox needs changing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake.  This code actually worked, but I thought it didn't work a few times even though it did.  I actually tried using a different Youtube video, and it wasn't working because I manually coded what src equaled incorrectly as opposed to just right-clicking the Youtube video and selecting "Copy embed html".  So the problem had nothing to do with browsers, addons, plugins, extensions, or updates.  I just had incorrect code for src.

Note: Use the "Copy embed html" feature as opposed to manually trying to enter in the code.